# Two (discrete) graphics cards in the same system?

Tags: windows, display, nvidia-graphics-card

There are two GPUs, one is Geforce 580gtx, the other is Geforce titan, I want to use the first one for mostly game/general desktop applications, whilst the other one for mostly CUDA applications.

So GF110 is inserted into the primary PCIE-16 slot, whilst GK110 occupies the secondary PCIE-16 slot.

I also connected the DVI cable to GF110 and VGA cable to GK110, both VGA and DVI cables are then connected to one monitor.

As long as I let 580GTX stick to display role and Titan stick to CUDA role, they work fine, however, if I try to switch the cards for display role (let Titan to display through setting up in Nvidia driver control panel), then the screen stops refreshing and is basically frozen.

However, if I take out the DVI cable physically and only let the monitor connects to the Titan card, then Titan can output display signals properly.

Anyone know how to switch the two discrete cards in windows?

The driver for both cards is the latest 314.21 beta (I tried 314.09 WHQL, and it didn't work either).

The motherboard being ASUS X79, CPU being 3960X, OS being Windows 7-64 bit.

Comment: You want both monitors connected to the same card.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: So I cannot have two cards connected to one monitor and switch between them just sort of how nvidia optimus work? I dont think so.

Comment: You can, but you don't want to. Pick the card that you want to use for 3D and connect the monitors to that card.